# Difference between using lists of arrays and individual arrays in scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu

Tags: python, statistics

I have been tinkering with the scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu function but I am afraid I don't quite understand what inputs should be used. I tried reading the documentation on the scipy site (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html#scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu) but it does not mention the difference between "one to one" comparison and "list of arrays vs list of arrays" comparison.

I have a function (create_vector) that outputs a length 10 array (vector) corresponding to a population for a given year. I want to make sure that for all years, the distributions are different. So I tried to do a "one to one" comparison and a "list of arrays" comparison, expecting to see the same results. However, this was not what I observed:

```
reps = 10
test_mannwhitneyu1 = []
test_mannwhitneyu2 = []
individual_pval = []
for year in df['Year'].unique():
    _, _, vector1 = create_vector(df, year, ['BB'], reps, seed = np.random.randint(1000))
    _, _, vector2 = create_vector(df, year, ['B'], reps, seed = np.random.randint(1000))
    test_mannwhitneyu1.append(vector1)
    test_mannwhitneyu2.append(vector2)
    pval = stats.mannwhitneyu(vector1, vector2).pvalue
    individual_pval.append(pval)
    print('Year:', year, '\n', 'vector1:', vector1, '\n', 'vector2:', vector2, '\n', 'p-value:', pval)
print('One to one comparison p-value: \n', individual_pval)
print('List comparison p-value: \n', stats.mannwhitneyu(test_kruskal1, test_kruskal2).pvalue)
```

Output:

```
Year: 2000 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.011764705882352941, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.011764705882352941] 
 vector2: [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.8333333333333334, 0.16666666666666666, 0.5, 0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 0.16666666666666666, 0.8333333333333334] 
 p-value: 0.0005422930189281866
Year: 2001 
 vector1: [0.041237113402061855, 0.020618556701030927, 0.030927835051546393, 0.020618556701030927, 0.010309278350515464, 0.041237113402061855, 0.08247422680412371, 0.020618556701030927, 0.061855670103092786, 0.020618556701030927] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 0.46415381982146253
Year: 2002 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 1.0
Year: 2003 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.058823529411764705, 0.0, 0.058823529411764705, 0.0, 0.0, 0.058823529411764705] 
 p-value: 0.07671597678760604
Year: 2004 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 1.0
Year: 2005 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.00909090909090909, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 0.36812025069351895
Year: 2006 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 1.0
Year: 2007 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.09090909090909091, 0.030303030303030304, 0.0, 0.12121212121212122, 0.06060606060606061, 0.0, 0.030303030303030304, 0.12121212121212122, 0.030303030303030304, 0.12121212121212122] 
 p-value: 0.0007165387086095488
Year: 2008 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.27586206896551724, 0.1724137931034483, 0.3448275862068966, 0.2413793103448276, 0.2413793103448276, 0.2413793103448276, 0.3448275862068966, 0.3103448275862069, 0.3103448275862069, 0.2413793103448276] 
 p-value: 5.8493119157503726e-05
Year: 2009 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 1.0
Year: 2010 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07692307692307693, 0.02564102564102564, 0.05128205128205128, 0.02564102564102564, 0.02564102564102564, 0.0, 0.07692307692307693] 
 p-value: 0.005829764462212962
Year: 2011 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.05555555555555555, 0.037037037037037035, 0.037037037037037035, 0.05555555555555555, 0.09259259259259259, 0.05555555555555555, 0.037037037037037035, 0.09259259259259259, 0.16666666666666666] 
 p-value: 0.00021798911258822827
Year: 2012 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 1.0
Year: 2013 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.05084745762711865, 0.0, 0.03389830508474576, 0.00847457627118644, 0.00847457627118644, 0.03389830508474576, 0.025423728813559324, 0.01694915254237288, 0.00847457627118644, 0.025423728813559324] 
 p-value: 0.00022234443108803945
Year: 2014 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.013888888888888888, 0.020833333333333332, 0.013888888888888888, 0.013888888888888888, 0.006944444444444444, 0.020833333333333332, 0.013888888888888888, 0.006944444444444444, 0.013888888888888888, 0.020833333333333332] 
 p-value: 5.3074584364790525e-05
Year: 2015 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.027210884353741496, 0.013605442176870748, 0.02040816326530612, 0.006802721088435374, 0.006802721088435374, 0.02040816326530612, 0.02040816326530612, 0.027210884353741496, 0.013605442176870748, 0.027210884353741496] 
 p-value: 5.9363235094083226e-05
Year: 2016 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.015267175572519083, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015267175572519083, 0.0, 0.007633587786259542, 0.0, 0.022900763358778626, 0.015267175572519083, 0.015267175572519083] 
 p-value: 0.00568943346901249
Year: 2017 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.02127659574468085, 0.014184397163120567, 0.0070921985815602835, 0.014184397163120567, 0.0070921985815602835, 0.014184397163120567, 0.02127659574468085, 0.0070921985815602835, 0.014184397163120567, 0.0] 
 p-value: 0.00020946650272210413
Year: 2018 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.013605442176870748, 0.006802721088435374, 0.013605442176870748, 0.006802721088435374, 0.0, 0.006802721088435374, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.006802721088435374] 
 p-value: 0.005661591774844999
Year: 2019 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.012987012987012988, 0.025974025974025976, 0.025974025974025976, 0.05844155844155844, 0.032467532467532464, 0.032467532467532464, 0.05844155844155844, 0.025974025974025976, 0.032467532467532464, 0.032467532467532464] 
 p-value: 5.720642436833648e-05
Year: 2020 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 1.0
Year: 2021 
 vector1: [0.0, 0.006666666666666667, 0.013333333333333334, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.013333333333333334, 0.006666666666666667, 0.0] 
 vector2: [0.006535947712418301, 0.013071895424836602, 0.0, 0.0, 0.006535947712418301, 0.0, 0.006535947712418301, 0.006535947712418301, 0.0, 0.0] 
 p-value: 0.8352355863829577
One to one comparison p-value: 
 [0.0005422930189281866, 0.46415381982146253, 1.0, 0.07671597678760604, 1.0, 0.36812025069351895, 1.0, 0.0007165387086095488, 5.8493119157503726e-05, 1.0, 0.005829764462212962, 0.00021798911258822827, 1.0, 0.00022234443108803945, 5.3074584364790525e-05, 5.9363235094083226e-05, 0.00568943346901249, 0.00020946650272210413, 0.005661591774844999, 5.720642436833648e-05, 1.0, 0.8352355863829577]
List comparison p-value: 
 [0.00098037 0.00089695 0.00099802 0.00032497 0.00369469 0.00538675
 0.00019917 0.00019917 0.01059536 0.00022314]
```

What is the difference between doing it one way versus the other? Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `test_kruskal1` and `test_kruskal2` in the last statement are supposed to be `test_mannwhitneyu1` and `test_mannwhitneyu2`. In that case, I think you need to use [`scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu`'s](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) `axis=1` argument to ensure that you are performing the test with corresponding rows. By default, `axis=0` performs the test between corresponding columns.

Adjusting your code to use randomly generated data and `axis=1`:

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(854244528365483456)
reps = 10
test_mannwhitneyu1 = []
test_mannwhitneyu2 = []
individual_pval = []
for year in range(2000, 2022):
    vector1 = rng.random(size=reps)
    vector2 = rng.random(size=reps)
    test_mannwhitneyu1.append(vector1)
    test_mannwhitneyu2.append(vector2)
    pval = stats.mannwhitneyu(vector1, vector2).pvalue
    individual_pval.append(pval)
    print('Year:', year, '\n', 'vector1:', vector1, '\n', 'vector2:', vector2, '\n', 'p-value:', pval)
print('One to one comparison p-value: \n', individual_pval)

# Note the use of `axis=1`
print('List comparison p-value: \n', stats.mannwhitneyu(test_mannwhitneyu1, test_mannwhitneyu2, axis=1).pvalue)
```

we get

```
Year: 2000 
 vector1: [0.73650992 0.98696894 0.7563967  0.27336931 0.71123498 0.52019134
 0.42563068 0.6716014  0.74676209 0.11498433] 
 vector2: [0.07370246 0.84104495 0.97975122 0.08142437 0.4229992  0.87956518
 0.5776476  0.21761807 0.30357648 0.0253084 ] 
 p-value: 0.3074894566186813
Year: 2001 
 vector1: [0.07264363 0.3952469  0.4754504  0.54073087 0.95826597 0.47733047
 0.55375481 0.58916612 0.86543855 0.73477328] 
 vector2: [0.16456169 0.66274332 0.41546977 0.98301376 0.28690995 0.77639913
 0.64716321 0.77617615 0.66737532 0.90611527] 
 p-value: 0.47267559351158717
Year: 2002 
 vector1: [0.98579638 0.39334207 0.61188533 0.45318491 0.29880219 0.29294227
 0.97635468 0.31429103 0.26900044 0.35669534] 
 vector2: [0.48968763 0.31738357 0.3357193  0.23773466 0.32041307 0.57771978
 0.78033708 0.59624148 0.16623191 0.96824184] 
 p-value: 0.9698499769931556
...
Year: 2020 
 vector1: [0.31902957 0.97683205 0.49973995 0.56121242 0.88174085 0.44130758
 0.25972658 0.65827932 0.3450055  0.6791563 ] 
 vector2: [0.26725887 0.96564832 0.64527602 0.2059083  0.37548619 0.07441006
 0.37966708 0.85655498 0.39081974 0.51466021] 
 p-value: 0.3846730627355087
Year: 2021 
 vector1: [0.19274235 0.71499466 0.08004435 0.56102993 0.61065372 0.20897949
 0.75483436 0.27308547 0.4624456  0.16894812] 
 vector2: [0.75776582 0.89391257 0.33761929 0.74579376 0.97042512 0.74146194
 0.43942204 0.76689398 0.7823597  0.89278395] 
 p-value: 0.004586392080253494
One to one comparison p-value: 
 [0.3074894566186813, 0.47267559351158717, 0.9698499769931556, 0.9698499769931556, 0.10410988966022681, 0.5205228832757727, 0.27303633975118835, 0.0211339281291611, 0.6231762238821174, 0.6775849579524755, 0.18587673236587576, 0.5205228832757727, 0.4273553138978077, 0.8501067391385259, 0.7337299956962472, 0.7913367801006604, 0.24132159301718004, 0.3846730627355087, 0.5707503880581739, 0.031209012771740218, 0.3846730627355087, 0.004586392080253494]
List comparison p-value: 
 [0.30748946 0.47267559 0.96984998 0.96984998 0.10410989 0.52052288
 0.27303634 0.02113393 0.62317622 0.67758496 0.18587673 0.52052288
 0.42735531 0.85010674 0.73373    0.79133678 0.24132159 0.38467306
 0.57075039 0.03120901 0.38467306 0.00458639]
```